# Oversize DB restore to SQLExpress

Tags: sql-server, restore

I made a back of an express DB, it was 14.7GB big (how is this possible) but anyway, I need to restore it back to express but obviously it is too big, but there must be somehow I can do this. I need to get it restored and then I can shrink it. Please help this is urgent and need to get it up in 1 hour.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just do the restore. Did you try it?

SQL Server will create the mdf and ldf files for you, with the same size they had when the backup was produced. And if the backup came from an express, then it shouldn't be possible to have a more than 10 GB size mdf - and there's no restriction on the ldf.

So just try the restore command (possibly using the GUI) and if it doesn't work, let us know what command you executed (you can script it in SSMS) and the error message(s) you got.